# Redis SCAN returns invalid cursor

Tags: java, redis-cluster, lettuce

while executing below code

```
KeyScanCursor<String> cursor = syncCommands.scan(ScanArgs.Builder.limit(50).match(match));
List<String> values = null;
while (!cursor.isFinished()) {
for (String key : cursor.getKeys()) {
    values = syncCommands.lrange(key, 0, 50);
    }
    cursor = syncCommands.scan(cursor, ScanArgs.Builder.limit(50).match(match));
}
```

getting empty result but while executing below command

```
redis-cli --cluster call 127.0.0.1:30001 SCAN 0 MATCH "orgId:EC:resetPasswordExpiryHours"
```

getting expected result

```
127.0.0.1:30003: 22
 orgId:EC:resetPasswordExpiryHours
```

could someone help me why above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your last iteration of scan is ignored. Cursor is finished, but you have not processed returned keys.